Order of pins for AC mains connection to PCBs
I am designing an AC mains connector footprint in KiCAD which will be implemented using three 4.8 mm faston tabs for line hot, neutral and ground.

Is there a norm or preferred order for the order of the pins of such a connector? For example, hot surrounded by neutral and ground to offer a bit of protection to wandering hands? A side notes, all wiring to the tabs will have insulating boots and slots will be milled on the PCB where needed.
Thanks in advance, Joris
EDIT
Here is the finished footprint based on the accepted answer, complete with labelling and built-in milled slots (other slots will be needed on the board for complete isolation):

Thanks to all !

Not an answer to your question, but be aware of creepage between them on the PCB.

@winny thanks for the advice. I have spaced the pins 8 mm which is what I measured on  the hot/neutral terminals of a double pole switch. I might add 0.5mm to account for the pads width. Should I put a slot in-between the tabs?

The needed creepage clearance depends on pollution degree, air pressure, humidity, PCB board material...

There is no standard, but e.g. many if not most power supplies have PE between mains and low voltage side, with usually Neutral is right next to PE, and Live right next to Neutral.
The PE-N-L order might be used more often than with the PE in the middle, because in some cases, the PE might be omitted from the terminal since the power supply metal frame will be connected to PE terminal anyway, and the power supply metal frame is connected to metal chassis, and the mains inlet PE must connect to chassis.
The PE-N-L order might be also used for multi-input supplies which can take two live phases in so there is no neutral wire, but PE-L-L, which is more logical than L-PE-L, especially considering the expansions with neutral and multiple phases where the order could be PE-N-L1-L2-L3.
So to avoid errors, it makes sense to use a common logical layout that's already used by many. I am sure other layouts exist too and there may be a logical explanation why it is in use, such as your suggestion to put live between PE and N.

PE-N-L it is then ! Plus on boards that use it I will put the PE tab close to low voltage (control) side like you mention. Many thanks.
